# My arraylist resets itself after I run the servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I started working on a project where an admin, when logged in should via an web interface do the following:

- Create a new operator
- Show a list of all operators in the system.

I'm trying to implement this, but my arraylist keeps resetting it self to default.

Have created these files so far, and tried to point out who knows who:

login.html ---> admin.jsp (When you log in, you get to admin.jsp)

I have create 2 buttons in admin.jsp, named showList and AddNewOperator.

**First scenarie:**

When you click on AddNewOperator you get redirected to ---> create.jsp where you
have to enter name, cpr and ini.
After that you will be pointed too a servlet called "newOperator", here I run the doPost method, I have posted here.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {

    boolean completed = false;
    RequestDispatcher rd = null;

    String cpr = request.getParameter("cpr-nr");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String ini = request.getParameter("ini");

    Function func = new Function();

    try {
        completed = func.addNewOperator(cpr, name, ini);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception, error found!!!");
    }

    if (completed == true) {
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Succes.jsp");
    }
    else {
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Error.jsp");
    }
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

So when you run this code, it will add a new operator to my arraylist. My problem is that my arraylist keeps resets itself if i get back to the admin.jsp page and click on showList.

When it have created a new operator successfully, it will forward the admin to Succes.jsp where it tells it has been created.

Succes.jsp you see here:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Succes!</title>
</head>
<body>

New user created!

<form method="GET" action="Administration.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You see an form where you will get back to admin.jsp. Here you can click on showList button, and a new servlet will run!

**Second scenarie:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Function func = new Function();

    List opr = null;

    out.println("Operators in system:" + "<br>");
    try {
        opr  = func.showlist(opr);

        for(int i = 0; i < opr.size(); i++){
            out.println(opr.size());
            out.println(opr.get(i) + "<br>");     
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.print("Error found, when trying to show list");
    }

}
```

So if I run this code, it will print whats in my arraylist, but the new created operator is not there anymore, cause it have resets it self somehow.

Have tried putting this code into the other servlet (first scenarie)
Here it will print correctly, and i see the new created operator.

What is wrong? Why does it resets itself? It should only reset when I close the program down.

Comment: You don't actually give the code that defines/declares/initializes/etc the ArrayList....

Comment: What's happening in the `Function` class, `showlist` method? In scenario two, you're creating a new `Function` object each time, is this creating a new `ArrayList`?

Comment: Maybe you right. i think its creating a new arraylist, so maybe i should just create 1 servlet and handle it all in that?

Comment: Works now.. i guess i only should have used 1 Function func = new Function :) thx